# C++ operator overloading [] and return types

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, square-bracket

I'm just revisiting C++, and I have a question about overloading of the [] operator, and more specifically why my program doesn't work.

Given the following code in vec.cpp:

```cpp
double Vec::operator[](unsigned int i) const {
    return this->values[i];
}

double & Vec::operator[](unsigned int i) {
    return this->values[i];
}
```

These are defined in vec.h as methods to the Vec class, and if I do not use the operator in my main.cpp, all is fine and dandy. It compiles just as normal with no errors.

However once I do this in my main function (which is using std::cout and std::endl):

```
cout << a[0] << endl;
```

Things go wrong. The errors I get are a bunch of

```
candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'Vec' to 'char' for 2nd argument
operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, char __cn)
```

where you can replace 'char' with any primitive data type.

**Here is a working example**

```cpp
// In vec.h
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Vec {
    private:
        int dims;
        double *values;
    public:
        Vec(int dims, double values[]);
        double operator [](unsigned int i) const;
        double& operator[](unsigned int i);
};
```

```cpp
// In vec.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

#include "vec.h"

using std::cerr, std::endl, std::cout;

Vec::Vec(int dims, double values[]) {
    this->dims = dims;
    this->values = new double[dims];
    for(int i = 0; i < dims; i++) {
        this->values[i] = values[i];
    }
}

double Vec::operator[](unsigned int i) const {
    if(i >= this->dims) {
        cerr << "Elem out of range" << endl;
    }
    return this->values[i];
}

double & Vec::operator[](unsigned int i) {
    if(i >= this->dims) {
        cerr << "Elem out of range" << endl;
    }
    return this->values[i];
}
```

```
// In main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "vec.h"

using std::cout, std::endl;

int main() {
    double avals[2];
    avals[0] = 1.0;
    avals[1] = 2.0;
    Vec *a = new Vec(2, avals);

    cout << a[0] << endl; // Error occurs here

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me sort this out?

Comment: Will add @FredLarson

Comment: Needs to be `(*a)[0]`! `a[0]` is equivalent to `a.operator[](0)`, note the period. The same applies for all other operators, too.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Ah! Noted.

Comment: Unrelated but **beware**! The constructor of `Vec` allocates an array with `new`... Per the rule of 5, you should delete the array in the destructor, and provide custom copy constructor and copy assignment operator, or delete them, and the same for move...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this declaration

```
Vec *a = new Vec(2, avals);
```

there is declared a pointer of the type `Vec *`. So an expression with the dereferenced  pointer has the type `Vec`.

So in this statement

```
cout << a[0] << endl;
```

the expression `a[0]` has the type `Vec`.

It seems you mean

```
( *a )[0]
```

or

```
a[0][0]
```

Comment: Or possibly `Vec a(2, avals);`, in which case `a[0]` would be correct. There's no obvious reason for the dynamic allocation here.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. That worked.